# Dynamically retrieving values of a list object using properties as other object values

Tags: c#

I have two objects 
1)

```
        public class EmailData
        {           
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Urn { get; set; }
        public string FileBase { get; set; }
        public string EmailFrom { get; set; }
        public string EmailTo { get; set; }
        public string EmailSubject { get; set; }
        public string ContentType { get; set; }
        public int Size { get; set; }
    }
```

2)

```
  List<IndexNames> emailIndex = new List<IndexNames>()
        {
            new IndexNames
            {
                INDEXDescription = "URN",
                INDEXName = "URN",
                INDEXNumber = 1
            },
            new IndexNames
        {
            INDEXDescription = "EmailFrom",
            INDEXName = "EmailFrom",
            INDEXNumber = 2
        },
           new IndexNames
        {
            INDEXDescription = "EmailTo",
            INDEXName = "EmailTo",
            INDEXNumber = 3
        }

        };
```

i have the
**List < EmailData>**
 with values.

How can i retrieve values(URN, EmailFrom, EmailTo) from the List < EmailData> whose property names are dynamically used from the 2nd(emailIndex) list URN, EmailFrom, EmailTo.

if a 4 emailIndex is added assume

```
       new IndexNames
        {
            INDEXDescription = "EmailSubject",
            INDEXName = "EmailSubject",
            INDEXNumber = 4
        }
```

i should dynamically get the 4 property values (URN,EmailFrom,EmailTo,EmailSubject) from List

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You say you have a list of EmailData ***with values***. So are you saying that within each EmailData object the URN etc. is populated?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching i got the solution for my own question.. this can be achieved by using Reflections

```
foreach (EmailData doc in docList)
        {
 foreach (var index in IndexNames)
                {
        var propName = index.INDEXName;
      tcCell.Text = doc.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(doc, null).ToString();
 }
```

This retrieves the values in 
the below format

```
-------------------------------------------
|URN    |EmailFrom   |   EmailTo       |
-----------------------------------------
| 1     | a@b.com    |   c@d.com       | 
| 2     | e@f.com    |   g@h.com       |
| 3     | i@j.com    |   k@l.com       |
-----------------------------------------
```